# Artifacts with classifiers not copying to local repository

Tags: maven-2, dependencies, maven, classification, artifact

I am using Maven version 2.0.7 and I am using the javadoc and source plugins to create additional artifacts for deploy. All of the generated artifacts are deploying correctly but it seems that when someone else builds they are only getting the specific artifact they specify. I don't want to have to add the source and javadoc artifacts as explicit dependencies i nthe other projects but I can't see any other way without changing something.

- Is this expected behaviour for the Maven version I'm using?
- What version does this stop, if any?
- Is there another way around the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I don't want to have to add the source and javadoc artifacts as explicit dependencies in the other projects but I can't see any other way without changing something.

You can use the following goals to get the sources artifacts and the javadoc artifacts respectively:

```
mvn dependency:sources
mvn dependency:resolve -Dclassifier=javadoc
```

The three major IDEs offer similar features (probably using the same goals under the hood).